# Block of sub-thread makes main thread blocking if sub-thread hosts a IE control

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I come across a weired problem now. Here is the situation:

Main thread hosts the main window.

Main thread creates a child window.

Main thread creates a child thread.

Child thread creates a IE Control.

Child thread attaches IE Control to child window.

The problem is once the child thread blocks(e.g. ::Sleep(10 * 1000 ), the main thread's GetMessage function can't get message any more which means main thread is blocked too!
I don't get it. why sub-thread can effect main threads?
If I comment the attch codes. blocks of child thread would not block main thread at all!

Below is the attach code snippet:

```
CComPtr<IUnknown> punkCtrl;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WebBrowser, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, (void **)&punkCtrl);
if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    m_spWebBrowser2 = punkCtrl;
    if( m_spWebBrowser2 )
    {
        CComPtr<IAxWinHostWindow> spWinHost;
        HRESULT hr = QueryHost(&spWinHost);

        if (spWinHost)
        {
            spWinHost->AttachControl(m_spWebBrowser2,m_hWnd);
        }
    }
}
```

Can Somebody help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just create COM objects (and UI) on another thread and pass them to main thread. Why don't create you create it on a main thread like other people do?

I think it is quite impossible to pass UI to another thread (message loops of main window and child controls are hosted on different threads, and child/parent notifications just won't work).

And as for COM, you need both initialize both threads for COM and marshal pointer between them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678428(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: THX for your reply. But I don't think I passed COM objects to main thread. The COM object here is m_spWebBrowser2 which is hosted by child thread. In main thread I use ::PostThreadMessage() to notify child thread to do staff.

Comment: You haven't passed it to main thread, but you've added it to UI on main thread. `m_hWnd` is your main window, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. I noticed that IE10 main window and tab window are under different threads, and of course It workes fine. The reason I did this is I don't want blocks of IE control effect main window.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the parent window need to syncronize messages with its child window which in hosted by another thread. So the two threads have some kind of connection. one is blocked, the other is blocked too!